# Substitute symbolic variables with autodiff variables

Tags: drake

I have some symbolic expressions stored on disk that I want to use in a non-convex program with autodiff variables. How can I substitute symbolic variables for autodiff variables?

```
from pydrake.all import (
    MathematicalProgram,
    SnoptSolver,
    Variable,
)

# Loaded from disk
x = Variable("x")
cost_expression = x**2

prog = MathematicalProgram()
x_vars = prog.NewContinuousVariables(1, "x")


def cost_func(vars):
    var = vars[0]
    return cost_expression.Substitute({x: var})


prog.AddCost(cost_func, vars=x_vars)

# Use Snopt with autodiff as the real problem won't be convex
solver = SnoptSolver()
result = solver.Solve(prog)
```

The above code gives the following error:

> result: MathematicalProgramResult = solver.Solve(prog) RuntimeError:
> Exception while evaluating SNOPT costs and constraints: 'TypeError:
> Substitute(): incompatible function arguments. The following argument
> types are supported:
> 1. (self: pydrake.symbolic.Expression, var: pydrake.symbolic.Variable, e: pydrake.symbolic.Expression) ->
> pydrake.symbolic.Expression
> 2. (self: pydrake.symbolic.Expression, s: Dict[pydrake.symbolic.Variable, pydrake.symbolic.Expression]) ->
> pydrake.symbolic.Expression
>
> Invoked with: <Expression "pow(x, 2)">, {Variable('x', Continuous):
> <AutoDiffXd 0.0 nderiv=1>}

Comment: Unfortunately we current don't have that functionality to replace the symbolic expression to autodiff yet.

Comment: I would think ExpressionCost and ExpressionConstraint can do the job.

Comment: I opened an issue in Drake based on Honkai's answer: https://github.com/RobotLocomotion/drake/issues/20696. I figured out how to do it manually in Python and added that approach there.

Comment: @jwnimmer-tri I wasn't aware of these, but they look great! They would also solve the toy example presented here. However, they wouldn't work for my actual problem as I want to add additional logic to the cost function that can't be represented as modifying the expression.

Comment: Your custom logic can call ExpressionCost::Evaluate as a subroutine, to get the value and grad of the raw expression.  If you want to further edit that value, you can still do that.

Comment: This is great and works beautifully. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you, Jeremy, for the great answer! I'm writing this up here so that it is marked as completed.
Substitution/ evaluation of a symbolic expression with autodiff variables is possible by converting it to an `ExpressionCost`.

```
from pydrake.all import (
    ExpressionCost,
    MathematicalProgram,
    SnoptSolver,
    Variable,
)

# Loaded from disk
x = Variable("x")
cost_expression = x**2
expression_cost = ExpressionCost(cost_expression)

prog = MathematicalProgram()
x_vars = prog.NewContinuousVariables(1, "x")


def cost_func(vars):
    return expression_cost.Eval(vars)[0]


prog.AddCost(cost_func, vars=x_vars)

solver = SnoptSolver()
result = solver.Solve(prog)
```